# Moving from CodeRush to ReSharper (or vice-versa). Any resources/help for making the transition?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, coderush

I've been using [CodeRush with Refactor! Pro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) for a while, but I'm considering moving to [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper).

Once I uninstalled CodeRush, I *immediately* began to miss some key features, including:

- navigating references using the Tab key,
- renaming variables, methods, etc. with the F2 key,
- basic refactorings such as Extract Method, etc.

I'm sure corresponding features exist in ReSharper.  But, aside from having to look through the [ReSharper online documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/) each and every time I find myself missing something, has anybody built a correspondence table of keyboard shortcuts, etc., to key features in common to each?  Or, if you've used both products yourself, could you share some basic equivalents you're aware of?

Note: this question is **not** being asked to debate which is better.  I like CodeRush, but I'd like to know **first hand** if I'd like ReSharper more. Getting up to speed with ReSharper quickly will help me assess it fairly.  For the which-is-better debate, please refer to the question [ReSharper vs. CodeRush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/resharper-vs-coderush).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This community plugin is typically useful for R#r users transitioning to CodeRush -> http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_ReSharperCompatibility

Comment: +1 thanks.  The image there covers some of the key features and has the ReSharper equivalent I'm looking for.